# How to send and wait for return message with spring cloud stream RabbitMQ?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

i'm trying to use the spring cloud stream for sending messages, but i'm not finding how do i send a message and get the return in the same method, same as I had using rabbitTemplate.

```
RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cf);
//configs template here...
Object test = template.convertSendAndReceive("Hello world");

//On Cloud Stream
private MessageChannel output;

public <T extends DomainEvent> void publish(T domainEvent){
    output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(domainEvent).build());
    //How to wait and receive the answer?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream is not designed for request/reply messaging.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the response Gary, but can i use rabbitTemplate at this point along with the spring stream without having conflict issues? Is that well in this part I need the consumer response :(

Comment: Yes you can use a rabbit template in a stream app.